# Github - failed to sync this branch [include logs]

Tags: github

I could successfully upload filed on Github from other computer.

However, it failed to sync uploaded files. I am suing Windows 8, and below image appeared.

[image]

So, I entered shell and typed "git status" and below lines showed up.

```
C:\Users\Playmobs Jake\Documents\GitHub\bridge [master +47 ~68 -0 !]> g
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working dire
#
#       modified:   .classpath
#       modified:   .project
#       modified:   AndroidManifest.xml
#       modified:   README.md
#       modified:   gen/com/playmobs/bridge/BuildConfig.java
#       modified:   gen/com/playmobs/bridge/R.java
#       modified:   gen/se/emilsjolander/stickylistheaders/R.java
#       modified:   proguard-project.txt
#       modified:   project.properties
#       modified:   res/drawable/bluetooth_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/border.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/border_topdown.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/dialog_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/endcall_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/friend_call_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/friend_dialog_call_selector1.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/hide_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/keypad_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/listview_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/mute_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/profile_edit_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/round_shape.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/search_invite_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/sign_confirm.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/sign_number.xml
#       modified:   res/drawable/speaker_selector.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/callscreen.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/fragment_friend.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/fragment_recent.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/fragment_search.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/fragment_setting.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/friend_dialog.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/friend_item_row.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/main.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/notice_item_row.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/option_dialog.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/profile_activity.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/recent_item_row.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/recent_list_header.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/ringscreen.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/search_item_row.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/signauth_activity.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/signup_activity.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/start_activity.xml
#       modified:   res/values-v11/styles.xml
#       modified:   res/values-v14/styles.xml
#       modified:   res/values/colors.xml
#       modified:   res/values/strings.xml
#       modified:   res/values/styles.xml
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/call_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/main_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/phoneFunction.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/profile_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/ring_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/signauth_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/signup_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/bridge/start_activity.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/ViewTimer.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/fragment_Friend.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/fragment_Recent.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/fragment_Search.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/fragment_Setting.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/friend.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/friendlist_Adapter.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/recentCallEntry.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/recentlist_Adapter.java
#       modified:   src/com/playmobs/widget/searchlist_Adapter.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .settings/
#       bin/
#       lint.xml
#       res/drawable-hdpi/Thumbs.db
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/Thumbs.db
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/bridge_logo.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/dot_.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/dot_selected.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/dropout_chenk_btn.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/dropout_chenk_btn_selected.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/dropout_comfirm_red_btn.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/friends_reset_btn.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/friends_reset_btn_selected.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/intro_logo.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/intro_signin_btn.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/intro_signin_btn_selected.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/intro_signup_btn.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/intro_signup_btn_selected.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/manual_1_image.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/manual_2_image.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/manual_3_image.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/playmobs_logo.png
#       res/drawable-xhdpi/playmobs_logo2.png
#       res/drawable/border2.xml
#       res/drawable/drop_out.xml
#       res/drawable/friends_sync.xml
#       res/drawable/signin_selector.xml
#       res/drawable/signup_selector.xml
#       res/layout/announcement.xml
#       res/layout/announcement_low.xml
#       res/layout/change_picture.xml
#       res/layout/company_introduction.xml
#       res/layout/drop_out.xml
#       res/layout/help.xml
#       res/layout/help_low.xml
#       res/layout/help_out.xml
#       res/layout/intro.xml
#       res/layout/intro_sub1.xml
#       res/layout/intro_sub2.xml
#       res/layout/intro_sub3.xml
#       res/layout/intro_sub4.xml
#       res/layout/splash.xml
#       res/layout/sqlist_low.xml
#       res/layout/sync_friends.xml
#       src/com/bridge/
#       src/local/
#       src/org/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
C:\Users\Playmobs Jake\Documents\GitHub\bridge [master +47 ~68 -0 !]>
```

Can you see what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the way that git protects you from overwriting data whenever you are pushing/pulling/merging files from one branch to another.

On your windows 8 computer, you have 4 new commits on the (local) master branch. On the remote master branch, origin/master, there is one new commit waiting for you.

It sounds like you were trying to pull from origin/master to local master, and it failed to sync the new commit from origin/master because it would have overwritten your new commits (or at least doesn't know how to mix them together).

You have some options here, but the main idea is that you want to merge changes from origin/master into your local master, and not lose any of your local commits in the process.

Your two basic options are to [rebase or merge](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html). To do this from command line, run

```
git checkout [yourbranch]
git pull --rebase origin master
```

You could also run

```
git checkout [yourbranch]
git merge origin/master
```

Either of these methods should mix the two branches safely and allow you to push new commits back to origin/master. You should receive information about how it is lining up the commits, and you can run `git log` to make sure everything looks right.

If there's a problem, use `git rebase --abort` to void a rebase. If you merged and want to go back, run a `git log` and find the merge commit. Then copy the long sha number of the commit *before* the merge commit, and then run `git reset [commit sha]`.

You may encounter problems because you have uncommitted changes on your local copy of master (otherwise known as a 'dirty working tree'). To get around that, either commit your changes and then do the rebase/merge, or [stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your uncommitted changes for later use. To stash, run the `git stash` command in the terminal, which will save and hide all uncommitted changes, letting you merge/rebase safely. Running `git stash apply` later will show your stashed changes and they will return just like they are in you pasted `git status` output.